# Dynamic Azure AD implementation for multi saas product

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, openid-connect, saml-2.0, azure-ad-msal

I am facing a problem in invoking the startup class on each instance when I try to authenticate using Azure AD.

Scenario 1:
I have SAAS products, and each product has its own SAML authentication. The code below is used to implement SAML, and it is set up in the startup class. Every time I call SAML to log in to a SAAS product, it goes to the startup class, fetches the particular SAAS products idpEntityID and idpMetaData from the database, and uses them for authentication. This flow works fine.

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddSaml2(Saml2Defaults.Scheme, samlAuthDisplayName, options => AddSAML(options, configuration, serviceProvider))
var samlProvider = serviceProvider.GetService<SamlExternalLoginProviderSettings>();
options.Notifications.SelectIdentityProvider =
    (id, data) => samlProvider.GetProvider(id, data, options );

options.Notifications.GetIdentityProvider =
    (id, data, soptions) => samlProvider.GetProvider(id, data, soptions);

SamlExternalLoginProviderSettings class:

// fetches idpEntityIDValue & idpMetaDataValue from the m database for respective saas product assigns below.
idpEntityID = "idpEntityIDValue";
idpMetaData = "idpMetaDataValue";
 return new IdentityProvider(
         new EntityId(idpEntityID), options.SPOptions)
 {
     LoadMetadata = true,
     AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = true,
     Binding = Saml2BindingType.HttpRedirect,
     MetadataLocation = idpMetaData,
 };
```

scenario 2:
I have successfully implemented SAML authentication for my SAAS products and now wish to integrate the same approach for Azure AD. However, I am struggling to determine how to invoke the startup process for each instance, as I haven't found sufficient resources online. I hope someone can provide assistance. Thank you.

```
services.AddAuthentication()
          .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options => AddMicrosoft(options, configuration, serviceProvider), null , OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, OpenIdConnectDefaults.CookieNoncePrefix, false, azureAuthDisplayName);
```